# $http.post в Angular не отправляет данные

Tags: angularjs, post

Доброго времени
Отправляю post-запрос серверу:

```
$http({
    method: 'post',  
    url: 'ajax/ajax1.php', 
    data: data
})
```

data - объект

[image: объект data - скрин консоли]

Сервер видит запрос, но не видит данных. 
Прошу его вернуть мне объект запроса, возвращает пустой массив.

Дело, видимо, не в Ангуляре, а во мне. Что я делаю не так?

Код следующий:

КЛИЕНТ:

```
var pageController = function($scope, $http, getUserInfo){
    var data = {
        u: $scope.userID,
        data_books: $scope.books.join(),
        data_days: $scope.days.join()
    };

    getUserInfo.getCompletedTasks(data)
        .then(function(value){
            $scope.userInfo = value;
        })
}

var getUserInfo = function($http){
    var getCompletedTasks = function(data){
        var data = data;
        data['action'] = 'getUserInfo';
        return $http({
            method: 'post',  
            url: 'ajax/ajax1.php', 
            data: {action: "hello"}
        })
          .then(function(data){
            return data.data;
          })
          .catch(function(err){
            console.log('error: ', err);
            return;
          });
    };
    return {
        getCompletedTasks: getCompletedTasks
    };
}
```

СЕРВЕР:

```
$arRes = [];
$arRes['message'] = 'ok';
$arRes['test'] = $_REQUEST;
echo json_encode($arRes);
```

АПД:
При этом get-запрос к файлу .json нормально отрабатывает

Comment: код выглядит корректным, без [mcve] который можно запустить и посмотреть - вряд ли что-то можно сказать

Comment: может все дело в опечатке. я вообще я `post` делаю так: `$http.post(url, {data: data})` и все работает

Comment: Может быть, дело в заголовках запроса? Какие тогда я должна поставить?

Answer (score 2):

Нашла статью с подробным объяснением

https://habrahabr.ru/post/181009/

PHP просто не понимает передачу Ангуляра с настройками по-умолчанию, поскольку он  передает данные с использованием Content-Type: application/json и { "foo": "bar", "baz": "moe" } строки JSON, которую, к сожалению, некоторые серверные языки изначально не преобразуют в объект.

Существует множество решений, суть их в том, что нужно либо изменить код сервера, либо схему использования $http, либо прописать настройки конфигурации для модуля приложения.

Comment: перенеси суть решения непосредственно в ответ. Ссылки могут быть только дополнением. Ответы состоящие из одной ссылки не приветствуются